# How to pass the list recursively using remove() method?

Tags: java, recursion

In this example I'm trying to use recursion to summate all the elements of a list. But there's a problem with `summation(l.remove(0))`, it has to return the tail of the list, but can not be applied here. How to do it correctly?

```
public static Integer summation(List<Integer> list) {
    return (list.isEmpty())
            ? 0
            : list.get(list.size() - 1) + summation(list.remove(0));
}
```

Comment: You could use [`List#subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)) or simply pass the index of the element that marks the head of the list around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work, but the list will be empty at the end (if you want to retain the original list, make the initial call to `summation` with a copy of the list created e.g. with `new ArrayList<Integer>(originalList)`)

```
public static Integer summation(List<Integer> list) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return list.remove(list.size() - 1) + summation(list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
public static Integer summation(List<Integer> list) {
    return (list.isEmpty())
            ? 0
            : list.get(list.size() - 1) + summation(list.subList(0, list.size()-1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This implementation may serve you better if you have lengthy lists.  Recursions which break a problem of size N into subproblems of sizes 1 and N-1 will quickly eat the stack.  This version breaks the problem into two subproblems of size N/2, so the stack growth is O(log N).  I was able to successfully run this with a test `ArrayList` containing 1,000,000 values, where the other proposed solutions had long since broken down with stack overflows.

```
public static Integer summation(List<Integer> list) {
   int currentSize = list.size();
   if (list.size() > 1) {
      int mid = currentSize / 2;
      return summation(list.subList(0, mid)) +
             summation(list.subList(mid, currentSize));
   } else if (currentSize == 1) {
      return list.get(0);
   } else {
      return 0;
   }
}
```

I know you asked for a `remove` based solution, but note that this approach can handle much larger lists and is not destructive of the original list.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is closer to the practice, reminds me of the quick sort approach "divide and conquer".